# Changing a 3D array to a 2D array that includes a list in Python/Pulp

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am using Solverstudio (with the Pulp solver) and i am trying to get a 2D output (onto a spreadsheet) from a 3D variable that has been found, for certain values of that variable.

Ive tried:

```
for (m,c,t) in mct:                 
 if Ymct[m][c][t].varValue>0:
  Schedule[m,t]=[c]
```

But since there's more than 1 c value for some m,t combinations, it doesnt work. I would like to have all the c values listed for the m,t combination.

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict` as `Schedule`, you can simply add `c`s to the list by:

```
from collections import defaultdict

schedule = defaultdict(list)
for (m,c,t) in mct:
    if Ymct[m][c][t].varValue>0:
    schedule[(m,t)].extend([c])
```

(As an aside, you should name your variables properly according to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Specifically, use `under_store` for variable names and function names, and `CapWords` for class names)

---

Update:

To write a `defaultdict` to csv, you can consider the following approach:    import csv

```
from collections import defaultdict

schedule = defaultdict(list)
schedule[1, 1] = [2, 3, 4]
schedule[1, 2] = [3, 4, 5]
schedule[1, 3] = [4, 5, 6]
schedule[1, 4] = [5, 6, 7]

with open("data.csv", "wb") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows([k, ] + v for k, v in schedule.iteritems())
```

---

Alternatively, I am wondering if `LpVariable.varValue` can return lists. And if so, the follwoing changes should work:

```
#schedule=defaultdict(list)
schedule = LpVariable.dicts("schedule", (moderator, time))

# ... many lines ...

for (m,c,t) in mct:
    if Ymct[m][c][t].varValue>0:
        #schedule[(m,t)].extend([c])
        schedule.setdefault(m, {}).setdefault(t, []).append(c)

# List entries in model output area
for (m,t) in mt:
    if len(schedule[(m,t)])>0:
        print (m,t), schedule[m][t]
        #print (m,t), schedule[(m,t)]

# ... many lines ...

for (m,t) in mt:
    timetable[m,t]=schedule[m][t].varValue
    #timetable[m,t]=schedule[m,t].items()
```

You can read over the changed code here: http://pastebin.com/UCVjqRwQ

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer (and the advise). Im new to python since I am only using it this one time to solve a linear model in excel (with solverstudio, but using the ironpython solver). 

I now used:

from collections import defaultdict
schedule = defaultdict(list)

for (m,c,t) in mct:
 if Ymct[m][c][t].varValue>0:
  schedule[(m,t)].extend([c])

for (m,t) in mt:
 if len(schedule[(m,t)])>0:
  print (m,t), schedule[(m,t)]

Comment: Im not sure if i did something wrong, but it still wont allow me to add the list to a cell in my workbook (and it isnt added when i use this code). I have schedule[(m,t)] defined on a range on my spreadsheet, but nothing changes on it. Im actually not even sure whether solverstudio (with pulp) allows lists in cells :S

I can at least get the answers in the model output section using the "print" command. It is better than nothing i suppose :D

If you have any additional ideas of what i may have done wrong, please let me know

Comment: @MarilizevanBuisbergen Without the code of how `Schedule` is used in the solver, I am afraid I won't be able to tell why it won't allow you to add the list to a cell..

Comment: its not used anywhere except at the end - its an empty table that is defined in the data of the model (using the add data option in solverstudio), and it has indexed rows (m) and columns (c). Its only function is to be filled in after the solution is found.

Comment: @MarilizevanBuisbergen I am not sure if I understand that completely. But the code I posted is no longer the `Schedule` in your original code; it basically declares a new variable `schedule` and modifies this `schedule` variable only. It gets filled by if you aren't using it later there's no way cells would be filled with the data stored in `schedule`.

Comment: for other variables i was able to use:

for (c,t) in ct:
 newmods[c,t]=Xct[c][t].varValue     (newmods is another spreedsheet table)

Is there perhaps a "Xct[c][t].varValue" type of thing that would work for a list (not a single number like with Xct)... like if i want to now put the data in "timetable"...

for (c,t) in ct:
 timetable[c,t]=schedule[c,t].???

Comment: @MarilizevanBuisbergen I'm afraid you will have to post your code for me to help you properly. There's no way for me to understand what each variables are for or how they are used withou context.

Comment: It wont let me add the entire code because its too many characters... could i email it to you perhaps? (to the email address on your website)

Comment: @MarilizevanBuisbergen Sure, or you can simply paste to pastebin.com and post the link

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EtnqLsB2

The datasets are all numbers, but i cannot paste them since they are selected on the spreadsheets using solverstudio

Comment: the problem is with the last part "for (m,t) in mt:
 timetable[m,t]=schedule[m,t].items()" (my latest attempt to put it in the table). Is there maybe (as an alternative) a way to export the schedule[(m,t)] to a CSV?

Comment: @MarilizevanBuisbergen I think for the last part, `for (m,t) in mt: timetable[m,t] = schedule[m,t]` would work. If not, I will update the solution with how you can export the schedule to a CSV file :)